# FlumeRpcClient multithreading

Tags: sdk, flume

I'm trying to understand the correct way to use the Flume RpcClient in a multithreaded application. Information I have found so far indicates that the components are thread safe, but the example in the Flume documentation clouds the issue when it comes to error handling.  This code:

```
public void sendDataToFlume(String data) {
    // Create a Flume Event object that encapsulates the sample data
    Event event = EventBuilder.withBody(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    // Send the event
    try {
      client.append(event);
    } catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
      // clean up and recreate the client
      client.close();
      client = null;
      client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
      // Use the following method to create a thrift client (instead of the above line):
      // this.client = RpcClientFactory.getThriftInstance(hostname, port);
    }
  }
```

If more then one thread calls this method, and the exception is thrown, then there will be a problem as multiple threads try and recreate the client in the exception handler.

Is the intent of the SDK that it should only be used by a single thread?  Should this method be synchronized, as it appears to be in the log4jappender that is part of the Flume source?  Should I put this code in its own worker and pass it events via a queue?

Does anyone have an example of RpcClient being used by more then one thread (included the error condition)?

Would I be better off using the "embedded agent"?  Is that multithread friendly?

Answer (score 0):

With the embedded agent, you get the same case except you don't know what to do:

```
try {
  agent.put(event);
} catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
  // ???      
}
```

You could stop the agent, and restart it - but you would need a synchronized block (or a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, to not block thread while "reading" the `client` field). But since I'm not a Flume expert, I can't tell you which one is better.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
  private final ReentrantReadWriteLocklock;
  private final Lock readLock;
  private final Lock writeLock;
  private RpcClient client;
  private final String hostname;
  private final Integer port;

  // Constructor
  MyClass(String hostname, Integer port) {
    this.hostname = Objects.requireNonNull(hostname, "hostname");
    this.port = Objects.requireNonNull(port, "port");
    this.lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    this.readLock = this.lock.readLock();
    this.writeLock = this.lock.writeLock();
    this.client = buildClient();
  }

  private RpcClient buildClient() {
    return RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
  }    

  public void sendDataToFlume(String data) {
    // Create a Flume Event object that encapsulates the sample data
    Event event = EventBuilder.withBody(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    // Send the event
    readLock.lock(); // lock for reading 'client'
    try {      
      try {
        client.append(event);
      } catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
        writeLock.lock(); // lock for reading/writing client
        try {
          // clean up and recreate the client
          client.close();
          client = null;
          client = buildClient();
        } finally {
          writeLock.unlock();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      readLock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Beside, the example will lose the event because it is not sent back. Some kind of loop + a max retry would probably do the trick:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < maxRetry; ++i) {
  try {
    client.append(event);
    break;
  } catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
      // clean up and recreate the client
      client.close();
      client = null;
      client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
      // Use the following method to create a thrift client (instead of the above line):
      // this.client = RpcClientFactory.getThriftInstance(hostname, port);
  }
}
if (i == maxRetry) {
  logger.error("flume client is offline, loosing events {}", event);
}
```

That's the idea, but I don't think that should be the task of the user (eg: us), but an option in the client or the agent to store event that could not be processed due to such errors.